# Temporary table in SQL Server 2014 causing ' There is already an object named' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporary, global-temp-tables

I have the following issue in SQL Server, I have some code that looks like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempLog') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE ##TempLog(id INT, name NVARCHAR(max));

INSERT INTO ##TempLog (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'Test')
```

When I do this I get an error

> There is already an object named '##TempLog' in the database

in SQL Server 2014, but in SQL Server 2016, everything is ok.

Comment: The first time I run that I get _String or binary data would be truncated._. After I add a size to nvarchar to get around that, and drop the faulty table, I can run it over and over again without issue. Your mistake with nvarchar makes me suspect this isn't your real code.

Comment: @ Nick.McDermaid thanks

Comment: Does your temp table need to be visible to other processes / users? If not, then you should only use one `#` instead of `##`. A single `#` means that each process can have its own temp table.  If more than one user runs the same process, then each has their own temp table.  `##` means the temp table is visible to all users.  If you use `##`, then the first user who runs it will create the temp table.  A second user will get an error.  And if the second user drops the `##` temp table, the first user may be negatively impacted. `##` also means the temp table persists after the user process ends.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempLog') IS NOT NULL
drop table ##TempLog
CREATE TABLE ##TempLog(id INT, name NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO ##TempLog (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'Test')
```

as @Nick.McDermaid was saying you should also replace  NVARCHAR

[image]

but it will work also over sql2012:

[image]

Comment: Did you copy my exact script and run it over tempb database?
because on my sql it woks without problems

Comment: Sorry I have SQL 2016 also!

Comment: I have test it and it will work also against sql2012, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.##TempLog
CREATE TABLE ##TempLog
  (
   id INT, 
   name NVARCHAR(10)
  )
```

If you want to use existing table use

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempLog') IS NOT NULL
    Truncate TABLE #TempLog
else
    CREATE TABLE ##TempLog
    (
        id INT, 
        name NVARCHAR(10)
    )
```